# CSS drawing lines

Tags: css, sass

Does anyone have an idea of how to draw these lines between the text and to be responsive? I've been working for 8 hours, I'm still at the beginning, and my brain is burning. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This is quit complicate you can achieve this by set left, right,top,bottom  border color with overlaping divs.

Comment: Did you try inspecting this in the Dev Tools?

Comment: This is image from pdf file. I try with divs and don't look like in image.

Comment: You, and others,  need to learn that CSS is not a graphic drawing tool.

Comment: I agrre with @Rob. Its easier with other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use bootstrap4 for responsive, and fake boreder with `:after`'s background, for border can not both gradient and radius

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.fakeimage {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

.left-bordered {
  background: white;
  border-right: 0 none;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.left-bordered:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  right: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.right-bordered {
  background: white;
  border-left: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.right-bordered:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  left: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3>
      <p>xxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="fakeimage"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 offset-2 left-bordered">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="fakeimage"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3>
          <p>xxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 right-bordered">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3>
          <p>xxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="fakeimage"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 offset-2 left-bordered">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="fakeimage"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3>
          <p>xxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 right-bordered">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3>
          <p>xxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="fakeimage"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 offset-2 left-bordered">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="fakeimage"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3>
          <p>xxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 right-bordered">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3>
          <p>xxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="fakeimage"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I want create. Thank you Josh!

Answer (score 2):

My best way of recreating the lines

EDIT
Improved the css for something more scalable.

```css
.line {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}


.line:not(.first){
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.right-side {
  margin-left: 15px;
}


.line1 {
  border-bottom: 1px blue solid;
  border-left: 1px blue solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.line2 {
  border-top: 1px blue solid;
  border-right: 1px blue solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.line3 {
  border-right: 1px red solid;
  border-bottom: 1px red solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.line4 {
  border-top: 1px red solid;
  border-left: 1px red solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line first line1">
</div>
<div class="line right-side line2">
</div>
<div class="line right-side  line3">
</div>
<div class="line line4">
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Change the colors and enjoy it:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px;
}
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer